# how to use Choice parameter in git action with conditions

Tags: github, devops, github-actions

I want to use choice parameter as input and jobs on basis of it. but unable to use it. I am getting error at: `if: ${{ inputs.environment == DEV || github.event.push }}`, getting error: `"Invalid type found: one of string, boolean were expected but choice was found"`

```yaml
name: TEST

run-name:  test:${{ github.event.inputs.environment }} 

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: choice
        description: Please select the Environment
        options:
        - DEV
        - QA

jobs:
  dev:
    if: ${{ inputs.environment == DEV || github.event.push }}
    uses: xyz/all/.github/workflows/dev.yml@main
    with:
      name: dev
      
  QA:
    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment == QA }}
    uses: xyz/all/.github/workflows/qa.yaml@main
    with:
      name: qa
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
github.event.inputs.environment.options
```

instead of `input.environment.options`

And is your if condition valid ?

shouldn't it be

```
jobs: dev: if: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment.options == 'DEV' }} || ${{ github.event.push }}
```

Comment: i tried in that way as well, still its not working !!!! showing the same error. @prudviraj

Comment: @RushikeshPisal i have not checked/tested , but i know there issue "Invalid type found: one of string, boolean were expected but choice was found"

The reason being `github.event.inputs.environment` would give both choice result , but we need to use `github.event.inputs.environment.options` to fetch the selected parameter , updated the answer check that now